# PDFBox Highlighting only the text

Tags: pdfbox

I am new to PDFBox; I have the following code to create a line with "Description" text in the line and fill the text in RED Color.

```
Row<PDPage> descriptionRow = table.createRow(25f);      
 cell = descriptionRow.createCell(50, "Description");       
 cell.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);        
 cell.setLeftPadding(50f);  
 cell.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD);      
 cell.setAlign(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);       
 cell.setFontSize(10f);         
 cell.setFillColor(Color.RED);
```

The code is filling the entire line till the end (almost 80 characters in length remaining characters filled with blank characters) text in RED Color.
I want to get only the highlighted text and not the entire line with blanks;

Any code snippet which accomplish this functionality

Comment: I suspect you're using another tool, maybe on top of PDFBox, maybe boxable or tabula. You should mention it.

Comment: To second @Tilman - your table, row, and cell classes in particular are not PDFBox classes.